# Is it possible to use intercepting route without using parallel route in next.js?

Tags: next.js, next.js13, next-router

In the nextjs document, it is said that Intercepting Routes can be used together with Parallel Routes to create modals. I want to know if this only applies to modal or should always be used intercepting route together with parallel route

I tried intercepting route without parallel route, but I didn't get an answer

Answer (score 0):

The nature of the intercept route is as its name: "intercept".
When you put the (..) convention to the route folder name, that route will intercept the main route - the one the user can access directly via URL.
In your case (the modal) - the reason for the intercept route being used here is to intercept the main route that renders the content of that modal. So, instead of rendering the page with modal content only, it will render the modal with modal content.

To answer your question: no, it's not applied to modal only.
But you are going in the wrong direction: why would you only want to use the intercepting route for modal? that will not make it become a modal - without the parallel route.